# Do pushouts preserve monic?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\matrix{ A& \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits^f &B\\\\
                 \Big\downarrow & & \Big\downarrow\\\\ 
              C& \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_g &D}$ 
be a pushout diagram in a category $\mathcal C$.

If $f$ is monic, is $g$ also monic? How to prove this easily? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the title to at least make it informative!


Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true, for example, in topoi and in abelian categories, but it fails in general: In $C=\mathsf{CRing}$ we have a pushout

$\matrix{ \mathbb{Z} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{Q}\\\\
                 \downarrow & & \downarrow\\\\ 
               \mathbb{Z}/2 & \longrightarrow & 0.}$

Comment: Many thanks @Martin Brandenburg.This example is quite beautiful.